# Collection of video samples with different codecs

Tags: audio, video, codec, iptv

I'm in a middle of trying to buy iptv device and of course different iptv devices supports different kind of file formats, video codecs and audio codecs.

Can someone recommend me a collection of videos which would be encoded using different versions and different video and audio codec - as much as possible different combinations.

I understand that supporting everything (all video and all audio codecs) is pretty much impossible - so it would be good if they are sorted in most used - least used order. For example:

1. .avi - xvid vx.xx video codec + yyy audio codec
2. .mkv - ....
3. YouTube .flv format ...
4. ...

But of course which codec is used and where depends of which movies you get and from where. I could perform ordering of videos on my own.

Preferably so that videos would be as small as possible - for example 20 seconds per clip, and some video / audio which you can easily inspect - understandable video / audio. (language does not matter)

I suspect also that this kind of collection does not exists - then it's ok to give me video clips for different codecs here, and I will collect them into one collection.

Eventually I want to place all these clips on usb stick - come to shop and try out which of clips can be played and on which iptv-device.

Answer (score 8):

Two collections of video test files are on kodi.tv site : [https://kodi.tv/media-samples/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161003143242/https://kodi.tv/media-samples/) (archived link - right click + save to download files) and http://kodi.wiki/view/Samples 
Another one is on the site of MPlayer: http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/